# Excel - rows compressed/squashed after filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel

A user has a spreadsheet and filters on all of the columns.  They find that when they filter by one of the columns, and then remove the filter by selecting "select all", some of the rows remain "squashed" once the column is unfiltered.  By this, I mean that the rows reappear, but some of them are very tightly condensed and have to be expanded.

Afraid I can't provide a copy of the spreadsheet due to data protection reasons, but any suggestions of possible causes would be appreciated.

Comment: try selecting the whole sheet and adjusting all rows to an even height, and un-wrap them

Answer (score 1):

I think it is almost certainly because you still have a filter applied on one or more of the other columns.

Make sure all filters are unchecked and it should return to normal

Comment: You can verify this by checking if the row header numbers on the far left are blue. If they are, then there's a filter somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

One possible reason I'm finding that some of the Columns or Row within the Filter area doesn't have same Height & width.